# Correct Generics using for List

Tags: java, generics

I have the next code:

```
class Cat extends Animal{}

List<Cat> oldCats = getCats();
List<Cat> newCats = doSomeWork(oldCats);

public static List<? extends Animal> doSomeWork(List<? extends Animal> animals){
    List<? extends Animal> newAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Animal a : animals){
        newAnimals.add(a);
    }
    return newAnimals;
}
```

I have compilation error, that required type is not correct.

```
Required type:List<Cat>
Provided:List<capture of ? extends Animal>
```

How properly tune generics for List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
public static <T extends Animal> List<T> doSomeWork(List<T> animals){
    List<T> newAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
    return newAnimals;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
But what if I want to do something with Animal instance inside doSomeWork mathod?
Updated the example...

Comment: You can do that, too.  Just use T.

Comment: @denis `T` supports everything of `Animal` since it **is** an animal. A dog is an animal. So you can write `T animal = animals.get(0)` and then `animal.eat()`. The only thing you can not do is `T`-specific stuff, such as `animal.bark()`. Cause that would require you to know that `T` is `Dog` (even though it could also be a `Cat`).

Comment: @Zabuzard, but I can't do this:
 newAnimals.add(a);

Comment: You should be able to do that. Sounds like you did some minor mistake somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't write `for (T a : animals)` like you should have.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<? extends Animal> doSomeWork(List<? extends Animal> animals){
  List<? extends Animal> newAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
```

Every time you use a `? extends Animal`, it means a different type of "something that is a subclass of `Animal`". So, the type of the parameter, the type of the return value and the type of the local variable are different: you can't add things from `animals` into `newAnimals` (or vice versa), and you can't return either `animals` or `newAnimals` from the method.

Also, that return type isn't "List of a particular type of animal", it's "List of a particular *but unknown* type of animal". You can't get a `List<Cat>` back from that, you can only ever get a `List<? extends Animal>`.

If you want to indicate that they are the same, you need to declare a type variable, which you use in all of the declarations.

```
public static <T extends Animal> List<T> doSomeWork(List<T> animals){
  List<T> newAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is still "some subclass of `Animal`", but the fact they are all referred to by the `T` means these are the *same* subclass; and the type that is returned is the same as the type you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Did it in such way:

```
public static <T extends Animal> List<T> doSomeWork(List<T> animals){
    List<T> newAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T a : animals){
        Animal castedAnimal = (Animal)a;
        newAnimals.add(a);
    }
    return newAnimals;
}
```

I don't like this casting... But it works

Comment: `castedAnimal` isn't actually used here. And the explicit cast is unnecessary anyway, because `a` is a `T`, and `T` is a subclass of `Animal`; so `Animal castedAnimal = a;` would work.

Comment: @AndyTurner
It's it's example...
Of course I use Animal instance, After using I place Animal to  newAnimals

Comment: You are saying "I don't like casting" about code where you don't need to cast. Example or not, just don't cast unnecessarily, particularly if you don't like it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Undestood...
You're right, casting is not necessary here